# Split a column into multiple binary dummy columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to split a single "character" variable in my dataframe into mutiple "factor" variables.

```
> sampledf=data.frame(vin=c('v1','v2','v3'),features=c('f1:f2:f3','f2:f4:f5','f1:f4:f5'))
> sampledf
  vin features
1  v1 f1:f2:f3
2  v2 f2:f4:f5
3  v3 f1:f4:f5

> desireddf=data.frame(vin=c('v1','v2','v3'),f1=c(1,0,1),f2=c(1,1,0),f3=c(1,0,0),f4=c(0,1,1),f5=c(0,1,1))
> desireddf
  vin f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
1  v1  1  1  1  0  0
2  v2  0  1  0  1  1
3  v3  1  0  0  1  1
```

I've tried using `strsplit()` to separate the "features" column

```
strsplit(as.character(df$features), ";")
```

but have had no luck factorising them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` after splitting (`strsplit(..`) the 'features' column.

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(sampledf[1],mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(sampledf$features), ':')))
#  vin f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
#1  v1  1  1  1  0  0
#2  v2  0  1  0  1  1
#3  v3  1  0  0  1  1
```

Or we can use `cSplit_e` from `library(splitstackshape)`

```
library(splitstackshape)
df1 <- cSplit_e(sampledf, 'features', ':', type= 'character', fill=0, drop=TRUE)
names(df1) <-  sub('.*_', '', names(df1))
```

Or using `base R` methods, we `split` as before, set the names of the `list` elements from the `strsplit` with 'vin' column, convert to a key/value columns 'data.frame' using `stack`, get the `table`, transpose and `cbind` with the first column of 'sampledf'.

```
cbind(sampledf[1],  
 t(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(sampledf$features), ':'), 
              sampledf$vin)))))
```

Comment: They work perfectly akrun! But is there a way to do this using base functions?

Comment: @outlier123 added a base R option.

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot Akrun!! (Rep too low to upvote publicly)